# ISNULL em um Case When

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, when

Estou fazendo um select utilizando o `CASE WHEN` no Sql Server, de modo que é feita a verificação da existência de um registro, se existir, faz select em uma tabela, senão, faz select em outra tabela, porém, as duas podem retornar null. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT Id FROM TabelaA WHERE ColA = 10)
    THEN
        (SELECT ColA from TabelaA WHERE ColA = 10)
    ELSE
        (SELECT ColA from TabelaB WHERE ColB = 10)
END Column
```

Como utilizar um `ISNULL` nesse script de modo a evitar um retorno nulo de ambos os selects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema de forma simples, (Até fiquei surpreso, não sabia que isso funcionava):

```
 ISNULL(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT Id FROM TabelaA WHERE ColA = 10)
          THEN
             (SELECT ColA from TabelaA WHERE ColA = 10)
          ELSE
             (SELECT ColA from TabelaB WHERE ColB = 10)
        END, '') Column
```

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma de resolução mais simples seria usando o [COALESCE](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
A vantagem do coalesce é que você pode fornecer uma lista de parâmetros e o primeiro não nulo é exibido

```
COALESCE(A,B,C,D..Z)
```

Se A é nulo então avalie B, se B é nulo então avalie C, etc..

A proposição de código eliminar a estrutura case:

```
Select Coalesce ((SELECT ColA from TabelaA WHERE ColA = 10), (SELECT ColA from TabelaB WHERE ColB = 10))
```

Veja um exemplo funcionando no [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b9622/1)

Comment: Eu não conhecia esse recurso. Obrigado.